# Unable to run junit-5 test cases from intellij idea

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

Junit-5 test cases run for me from command line successfully. I am using Maven and when I run using `mvn clean install` test cases run successfully but when to run individual test cases using IntelliJ it fails with the following error.

```
Feb 15, 2018 11:33:41 PM org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.JavaElementsResolver resolveMethod
WARNING: Method 'public static java.util.Collection com.softiventure.dtos.junit.parametrized.NestedParametrizedTest$sumTest.parameters()' could not be resolved.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute(Lorg/junit/platform/launcher/LauncherDiscoveryRequest;)V
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:59)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

My sample test class is :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

@DisplayName("Pass paramters ")
public class ParametrizedJunit5Test {

    @DisplayName("Should pass a non-null message to our test method")
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"Hello", "World"})
    void shouldPassNonNullMessageAsMethodParameter(String message) {
        assertNotNull(message);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: in a blog here https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/08/using-junit-5-in-intellij-idea/ it is suggested to use a dependency i added that and now the error message is bit different it says it's able to find the engine but not the test method.

Comment: to my surprise my idea version is 2016.3. Will upgrade it and try again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some compatability issues between JUnit5 and IntelliJ.

According to [the JUnit docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea) ...

> it is recommended to use IDEA 2017.3 or newer since these newer versions of IDEA will download the following JARs automatically based on the API version used in the project: junit-platform-launcher, junit-jupiter-engine, and junit-vintage-engine.

This [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/08/using-junit-5-in-intellij-idea/) from the IntelliJ team is also relevant. There's a [comment](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/08/using-junit-5-in-intellij-idea/#comment-418624) on that post from a user who encountered the same error as you and that user's response is:

> I update idea to 2017.2.6, it works well.

So, update to IntelliJ 2017.3 or newer and this issue should disappear.

Answer (score 3):

From offical comment, you may have to upgrade your IDE version

> IDE has compilation dependency on the old junit 5 launcher jar and it is not compatible with current released version. So you have a choice to update IDE so it will be compatible with the junit version you use or to downgrade the junit version (check what version was bundled in IDEA_INSTALLATION_HOME/plugins/junit/lib). 2017.1 had only experimental support for junit 5 as junit 5 was not released yet at that time. Sorry for the inconvenience.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000791190-Intellij-does-not-run-Junit5-tests

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My IDEA version is `2017.1 ver.`, when I run Junit5 test case, the blow error was occured.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute(Lorg/junit/platform/launcher/LauncherDiscoveryRequest;)V

and I updated IDEA to `2017.3.5 ver.`, that problem was resolved